# HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error eclipse

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, http-error, restfb

I am trying to run an app on Tomcat v9.0 and  have already wrote a function that supposedly 'prints' an html table based on an arraylist of data extracted using the library restFB. I have tested the restFB code in another project that doesn't run on a server and it works fine, but when I try to use a button and call the funtion inside the servlet it gives me the status 500 error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/restfb/FacebookClient
    Logica.FacebookCall.doPost(FacebookCall.java:49)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Here is the servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // doGet(request, response);
        String button = request.getParameter("button");
        if ("Obtener Datos".equals(button)) {
            FacebookCalls fb = new FacebookCalls();
            ArrayList<String> html = fb.getInfoMiembros();
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<table border=\"1\">");
            out.println("<tr>");
            for (int i = 0; i < html.size(); i++) {
                if (i > 0 && i % 4 == 0) {
                    out.println("</tr><tr>");
                }
                out.println("<td>" + html.get(i) + "</td>");
            }
            out.println("</tr>");
            out.println("</table>");
        }
    }
```

The `FacebookCalls fb = new FacebookCalls();` is a reference to another class in which I have the code that returns the arraylist of facebook data. Shown below:

```
public FacebookCalls() {}

public ArrayList<String> getInfoMiembros()
{
    String accessToken = "myToken";

    ArrayList<Persona> miembros = new ArrayList<Persona>();

    ArrayList<String> listaNombres = new ArrayList<String>();

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    FacebookClient fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);

    JsonObject fetchObjectsResults =
              fbClient.fetchObjects(Arrays.asList("352867045226094"), 
                       JsonObject.class, Parameter.with("fields","members{name,gender}"));

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(fetchObjectsResults.get("352867045226094").toString());
    JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONObject("members").getJSONArray("data");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
    {
        Persona miembro = new Persona();
        miembro.setNombre(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
        try {
            miembro.setGenero(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("gender"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            miembro.setGenero("No disponible");
        }
        miembros.add(miembro);
    }       
    for(int i = 0; i < miembros.size(); i++)
    {
        listaNombres.add(miembros.get(i).getNombre());
        //html.add(miembros.get(i).getGenero());
    }
    listaNombres = sortApellido(listaNombres);
    return listaNombres;
}
```

Comment: I) I hope no haven't posted a real token. II) The problem is that the class FacebookClient is not found. Where is this class defined? It is in a jar file? If it is you have to make sure you are inclding the jar in war file or else it is present on the servlet containter's lib folder.

Comment: It does come from a jar file, from the restFB external library, it is placed on the "Referenced Librares" section of the project

Comment: When you deploy is it included in the war file? Or otherwise is it present in the lib folder of tomcat? If you use eclipse, for it to be included in the war file,  in the java build path it has to be marked for export.

Comment: There is no war file, at least i think there isn't, and the project had been deploying fine without it. Is there a way to generate a war file and manually add the jar reference to it? EDIT: just marked the jar file for export in the build path and the same error popped up

Comment: how are you running it and which is the ide you are using?

Comment: I'm using eclipse java oxygen 3 I believe and running it on a localhost apache tomcat v9.0 server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167834/discussion-between-fprot-and-juan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to revision we did in the chat session, the problem is that the jar file containing the `com.restfb.FacebookClient` class is not being exported in the war file / deployed to the application server.

For the jar to be exported, besides of having it added to the java build path, it also has to be present in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the project.

In this case the jar file was added from an external location so it wasn't present itn the `WEB-INF/lib` folder,  hence not exported when deploying the application / or generating the the war file.

To solve the problem add the jar file to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the project.